# Why i can not call action method with ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` want to call action method in the view page,for that purpose write this ajax code:

```
$('#SaveBTN').click(function (e) {


            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SaveRecord",
                type: "POST",
                data:'', //JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData }),
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {

                        alert("Done");

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error has occured!!!");
                }
            });
        });
```

this is my button:

ثبت نام

and this is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveRecord()
        {
            return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

but when run the web application and fire button,get error segment alert in `ajax` ,How can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: `data:''`, I think jQuery thinks you try to pass a a querystring with parameters while you don't need parameters, try to leave it out

Answer (score 0):

With the question and code presented in the way it is there is no way to help. I recommend starting from ground zero and [**stepping through this tutorial**](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api).

Basically that^ link will get you through the basics of using web api in MVC to do AJAX calls and populate the page. There are some other methods however this is the best place for trying to learn what you're studying.